# Why are my T& and T&& copy constructors ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Myclass{
        private:
                int i;
        public:
                template<typename U>Myclass(U& lvalue):i(lvalue){cout<<i <<" template light reference" <<endl;i++;}
                //Myclass(Myclass &lvalue):i(lvalue){cout<<i <<" light reference" <<endl;i++;}
                template<typename U>Myclass(U&& rvalue):i(rvalue){cout<<i <<" template right reference" <<endl;i++;}
};

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
Myclass a(0);
Myclass b(a);
Myclass c(2);
return 0;
}
```

**error message:**

```
rightvalue.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
rightvalue.cpp:15:12: error: call of overloaded ‘Myclass(Myclass&)’ is ambiguous
rightvalue.cpp:15:12: note: candidates are:
rightvalue.cpp:10:23: note: Myclass::Myclass(U&&) [with U = Myclass&]
rightvalue.cpp:8:23: note: Myclass::Myclass(U&) [with U = Myclass]
rightvalue.cpp:4:7: note: constexpr Myclass::Myclass(const Myclass&)
rightvalue.cpp:4:7: note: constexpr Myclass::Myclass(Myclass&&) <near match>
rightvalue.cpp:4:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Myclass’ to ‘Myclass&&’
```

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57172

Comment: @MarkTolonen changing to `const U&` results the output of ` template right reference`

Comment: The bug was fixed for 4.9, feel free to play with it and report any issues you find with the new behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here is what happens (or rather, *should* happen): in order to resolve this constructor call

```
Myclass b(a);
```

The compiler has to perform overload resolution and decide, at first, which constructors are viable candidates.

The first thing to notice is that both constructors are viable: forms like `T&&` do *not* always resolve into rvalue references (that's only the case if what you are passing is an rvalue). That's what Scott Meyers calls ["universal references"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) (notice, that this term is not standard).

When the compiler tries to perform type deduction to see if the second constructor is viable, the type `T` in this case will be deduced to be `Myclass&` - since what you are passing (`a`) is an lvalue; and because of the reference collapsing rules, `Myclass& &&` gives `Myclass&`, so you end up with the same signature your first constructor has.

So is the call is ambiguous? As pointed out by [Marc Glisse in the comments to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999039/why-are-my-t-and-t-copy-constructors-ambiguous/16999060#comment24561208_16999039), and by [Jonathan Wakely in the comments to this answer](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11), **no**, it should not be (as the original version of this answer claimed - mea culpa).

The reason is that a special rule in the Standard specifies that the overload accepting an lvalue reference is *more specialized* than the overload accepting an rvalue reference. Per paragraph 14.8.2.4/9 of the C++11 Standard:

> If, for a given type, deduction succeeds in both directions (i.e., the types are identical after the transformations
>   above) and both P and A were reference types (before being replaced with the type referred to
>   above):
>
> — **if the type from the argument template was an lvalue reference and the type from the parameter
>   template was not, the argument type is considered to be more specialized than the other**; otherwise, [...]

This means the compiler has a bug ([the link to the bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57172) has been provided by Marc Glisse in the comments to the question).

To workaround this bug and make sure your constructor template accepting a `T&&` will be picked by GCC only when rvalues are being passed, you can rewrite it this way:

```
    #include <type_traits>

    template<typename U,
        typename std::enable_if<
            !std::is_reference<U>::value
            >::type* = nullptr>
    Myclass(U&& rvalue):i(rvalue)
    {cout<<i <<" template right reference" <<endl;i++;}
```

Where I added a SFINAE-constraint which makes the compiler discard this constructor from the overload set when an lvalue is being passed.

When an lvalue is passed, in fact, `T` will be deduced to be `X&` for some `X` (the type of the expression you pass, `Myclass` in your case), and `T&&` will resolve into `X&`; when an rvalue is being passed, on the other hand, `T` will be deduced to be `X` from some `X` (the type of the expression you pass, `Myclass` in your case), and `T&&` will resolve into `X&&`.

Since the SFINAE constraint checks whether `T` is not deduced to be a reference type and creates a substitution failure otherwise, your constructor is guaranteed to be considered only when the argument is an rvalue expression.

So to sum it all up:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Myclass
{
    int i;
public:
    template<typename U>
    Myclass(U& lvalue):i(lvalue)
    {
        std::cout << i <<" template light reference" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }

    template<typename U,
        typename std::enable_if<
            !std::is_reference<U>::value
            >::type* = nullptr>
    Myclass(U&& rvalue):i(rvalue)
    {
        std::cout << i <<" template right reference" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
};

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    Myclass a(0);
    int x = 42;
    Myclass b(x);
    Myclass c(2);
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3306dc4347a90be1be31b064c187c33e-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336).

Comment: But as @MarcGlisse notes, [DR 1164](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1164) says the lvalue reference overload should be more specialized than the "universal reference" one

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this. I will have to edit my answer